# Prevent extra column in one to one relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using `Entity-framework code first` approach.

`Table 1` looks like:

```
public class CreditUser : BaseEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CreditUserName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    public Accounts Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

`Table 2` looks like:

```
public class Accounts : BaseEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalGivenAmount { get; set; }

    public CreditUser CreditUser { get; set; }
}
```

And `fluent api` code:

```
public class AccountsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Accounts>
{
    public AccountsConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        HasRequired<CreditUser>(c => c.CreditUser)
            .WithOptional(a => a.Accounts)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); 

    }
}
```

It produces two columns like,

[image]

That extra column in the end `CreditUser_Id` came as automatically. I don't want that. Please help me to solve that issue.

**UPDATE**

`CreditUSer Table` Table structure

[image]

**Solution**

As per comments below I tried like in this

```
public class AccountsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Accounts>
{
    public AccountsConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired<CreditUser>(c => c.CreditUser)
            .WithOptional(a => a.Accounts)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}
```

by removing Key in `the fluent Api` and it is working.

Comment: What does the `CreditUser` database table look like?

Comment: It's needed for one-to-many relationship

Comment: please try after remove `public CreditUser CreditUser { get; set; }` this line from `Accounts` class

Comment: @TaherRahgooy the requirement is one credit user should have one row in accounts.

Comment: OK, this is a one-on-one relationship with one of them is optional, so there is a need for the primary key of the optional one in the required one as foreign key.

Comment: @TaherRahgooy  I reffered this link  http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @TaherRahgooy Thanks man. U r right. Its working now

Comment: In the link example StudentAddress is a weak entity, Its PK is  StudentId